# How do I create an HTML link to open an existing Android app?

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I'm creating a web-based dashboard on an Android device, and would like to open an installed Android app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camera.one.s10.camera in this case) from the browser.

How do I find the scheme and available intents from an existing app?

I understand the link format is

```
<a href="intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;end">Link</a>
```

and the scheme in this case is "com.camera.one.s10.camera", but the tutorials I have read (e.g. [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)) describe how to do this when creating one's own manifest, not discovering possible actions from an arbitrary app.

Thanks!

Comment: The installed app must support that scheme then the system will know how to dispatch other wise it might be the default behavior.

Comment: If you just want to open a camera, you can throw an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent. If you want to open that specific app, you needs to know what's the links format that they can handle it (from them).

Comment: @GratienAsimbahwe how would I simply open the app? Is there no way to discern that from the app itself?

Comment: @Wesely something like this? `<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.google.android.GoogleCamera.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE;package=com.google.android.GoogleCamera;end"> Open camera </a>` 
seems to just open the Play Store link for the app, but I probably have the syntax wrong...